# Playing a video in the home page by Django

Tags: django, video

I want to have a home page which plays a video when the site runs, and has a button in order to skip the video and go to the first page of the site
any advice to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a html5 video element and set it to autoplay. And also have a button linking to your homepage